# confused about toString method in object and Wrapper classes

Tags: java, overloading, overriding

I know this is silly question,but I am confused,and this is the best site where I find the perfect answers

There is **toString** method in object class,,whereas there is a **toString** method in each primitive wrapper classes also.one is with Static keyword,other is not.What is done there?overloading or overriding ?

In short,I mean to say,can we add static modifier to overridden classes? or **tostring** method in primitive wrapper classes are different to the toString method in object class

Comment: There is also a `toString()` instance method there, which overrides the method in `Object` class.

Comment: Huh? What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: Are you asking how it's possible to have two classes each containing a function with the same name?

Comment: confused about question

Comment: @SLaks no I didn't mean that,I was confused that there is a tostring method without static in object class,and there is toString method with static keyword in Wrapper classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time to understand your (confusing) question. I can suppose that you are speaking about primitive wrapper classes like `Integer` or `Long` that indeed have several *overloaded* static methods `toString()`. But each one of them has different signature.

The `toString()` method defined in `java.lang.Object` that can be overridden by subclasses does not accept arguments. The static methods `toString` that can be found in other classes (e.g. `java.lang.Integer`) accept arguments (e.g. `public static String toString(int i)`, `public static String toString(int i, int radix)` etc)

I hope my interpretation of your question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The static (if you mean this as "class") method cannot hide the instance method. You will get the compile time error if you attempt this.

Answer (score 0):

Each and Every Wrapper class overrides the toString() method